# Cannot enter if statement when object is null

Tags: java, android

I have an android app code (in Java) where I create a custom object:

```
ProductModel isModelAlreadyOnList = isModelAlreadyOnList(TagID);
Log.e("isModelAlreadyOnList", String.valueOf(isModelAlreadyOnList));
```

here's method isModelAlreadyOnList code:

```
private ProductModel isModelAlreadyOnList(String productEPC) {
    for (ProductModel product : productList) {
        for (String epcValue : product.getEpc()) {
            if (epcValue.equals(productEPC)) {
                return product;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The log I get right after creating the object is:

```
E/isModelAlreadyOnList: null
```

which means that this object is null. But when I try to enter an if statement I simply cannot. This part of my code is very simple and there're no methods or code between creating **isModelAlreadyOnList** and the **if** statement.

```
 if (isModelAlreadyOnList == null) {
 Log.e("model is null", "");}
```

I have no idea why I cannot see the above message in logcat. I have already tried using

```
isModelAlreadyOnList.equals(null)
```

but there was no change in the result. I couldn't find a working solution on stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you have elements in your `productList` or is it empty? Does `product.getEpc()` return some collection with values or is it empty? Also, semantically, this method should return a `boolean` because you're checking for some state. That way you don't have to handle any `null` values

Answer (score 0):

Your log statement prints `E/isModelAlreadyOnList: null`. You surmise that this means your call to `isModelAlreadyOnList(TagID)` returned `null`. A likely explanation.

You then check if the object so returned is null using an `if` check. The if check does not trigger. This means, **definitively**, that the object returned is **not** null.

So, let's revisit that likely explanation.

Your code returns a `ProductModel`. This class has a `toString()` method.

Perhaps the implementation of ProductModel looks like this:

```
class ProductModel {
    private String productName;

    @Override public String toString() {
        return productName;
    }
}
```

In that case, the `isModelAlreadyOnList` method returns an actual `ProductModel` instance, but its `productName` is either `null` or the string `"null"`, and you'd get **that exact log statement just the same**.

The only other explanation is that the code you are actually running is not the code you think you are running, i.e. that your compilation is going wrong or is not being deployed to where-ever you are running this in the way you think you are.

Comment: Ok, I changed this code slightly and now it's more like this:
`ProductModel isModelAlreadyOnList = isModelAlreadyOnList(TagID);
Log.e("isModelAlreadyOnList", String.valueOf(isModelAlreadyOnList));
String msg = String.valueOf(isModelAlreadyOnList);
Log.e("value is", msg);`
The msg is null (info from logcat). And the if statement looks like this:
`if (msg.equals("null")) { ...` and still does not work, I mean I cannot enter it

Comment: msg is either `"null"` or `null`; if an `if` to target either case is not working, it's door #2: You aren't running the code you think you are running. There is nothing in either your question or your comments that would allow anyone to help you out on that front; you'd need to add a lot of detail about what you're doing, if that is indeed the case.